# Setting an integer value before loop

Tags: java, loops

I have a loop like so

```
    int current = -1;

    for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
        ... some stuff 

        if (i > current || current == -1) {
            current = i;
        }
    }
```

So basically, I don't have an original value for current before the loop. Is this a good way to ensure current value is set to the first instance of i or could it be written better?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but what's the point of `current`, if you're just going to set it equal to `i`?

Comment: What do you need current for. After your if it is always i and after your for it is size - 1..

Comment: @barsju, as the code is structured now, `i` cannot be referenced outside of the for loop.

Comment: @SteveKuo sure but after the for loop current = size -1; Unless he has a break in the ... some stuff.. Which is why he should post his complete code or at least specify what he needs the current value for..

Comment: The code is just example code, please ignore most of it. Just a quick snippet to illustrate my question.

Comment: But it doesn't illustrate your question. We still don't know what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

This one works nicely if `current` will only be used inside the loop:

```
for (int i = 0, current = i; i < size; i++) {
    // etc..
}
```

Comment: I've got multiple variables set to -1 before the loop, the code above is purely an example. I imagine it will get messy to initiliase multiple variables like this inline?

Comment: @user1277546 Yes, it will look messy so I don't recommend it. Is there a problem with just initializing them all to 0, if that's where `i` is going to start?

Answer (score 0):

That's the usual way people do it, yes.

There's no need for `current == -1` though, since `i > current` will evaluate to `true` the first iteration, and `current` is set to `i` after that.

Comment: If `current` is not assigned (as perhaps you're suggesting), then the compiler will complain if it's referenced after the for loop.

Comment: @SteveKuo but he assigns `current` before the loop.